# How can I check that docker autentication with specific registry works?

Tags: docker, dockerpy

I want to validate that `docker login` against a **specific registry** worked successfully. How can I do this by using docker cli or docker-py API, without trying to perform another authentication.

Please keep in mind that registries can allow anonymous pulls, so doing a random pull is not a valid way to validate that authenticated access works.